Extract private key from .pfx file in android java
I want to extract private key from .pfx file. The key extracting from this code snippet is in format PKCS#1, but I want in format PKCS#8.

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
            char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            getPrivateKeyFromPFX(password);
            InputStream certificateStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certificate);
            keyStore.load(certificateStream, password);
            kmf.init(keyStore,password);
            Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                String alias = aliases.nextElement();

                if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                    PrivateKey keyEntry = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password);

                    byte[] bytes = keyEntry.getEncoded();
                    String somthing =(keyEntry.getFormat());
                    // Encode the private key to Base64
                    String base64PrivateKey = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT) ;

                    Log.d("PFXExtractor", "Private key extracted and encoded in Base64:\n" + base64PrivateKey);
                }
           }

I tried using this snippet to cenvert but still not luck
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey.getEncoded());
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey1 = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec);

I extracting this key from android and pass to flutter code using methodChannel where
    RSAKeyParser().parse("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n$keyStr\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----") as RSAPrivateKey;

this code use that key for decryption

Have you tried doing it all in Dart using https://pub.dev/documentation/basic_utils/latest/basic_utils/Pkcs12Utils/parsePkcs12.html ?

Can you provide example to get private key from PKCS12  to PKCS8 format in dart

Here's an example of reading a PKCS12 format keystore, using basic_utils:
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';

void main() {
  final values = Pkcs12Utils.parsePkcs12(
    File('somePfxKeyStore.p12').readAsBytesSync(),
    password: 'changeit',
  );

    final privatePem = values.where((s) => s.contains('PRIVATE')).single;
    final privateKey = CryptoUtils.rsaPrivateKeyFromPem(privatePem);
}

The parse method opens the PKCS12 keystore and extracts its private key and certificates as PEM formatted strings.
Once you have the private key in PEM format, you can use CryptoUtils.rsaPrivateKeyFromPem
Note that PBE2 isn't supported. If you need that, please contribute it. (In the meantime, simply use a PBE encrypted keystore using, say, PBE-SHA1-3DES which is supported by Java keytool and openssl pkcs12.)
